# How to count data values in multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with about 1500 records (rows) and 18 variables (columns) and 17 of those variables have either 'R' or 'S' as data values. I would like to count for each record how many of those 17 variables have 'R' and add a column that displays this count in the dataframe. I am fairly new to R so any advice is appreciated.

My R dataframe looks like this:

D1  D2  D3  D4  D5 ... D17  Pred
R     S     S     S    S   ... S     MDR
R     R     S     S    S   ... R     nonMDR
S     S     S     S    S   ... S     SS
.
.
.

I would like to add a count column in this dataframe that tells me how many 'R' each row has. If the first record has 1 'R', the count would be 1; if second record has 3 'R', the count would be 3; and if the record has no 'R', the count would be 0.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `df$count <- rowSums(df == 'R')`